# extract no of click between date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to extract total no of click time wise (like week wise or month wise) from table bannerstatclick where bannerstatclick table have these column (idBannerStats: integer, Time: Timestamp, idCampaignBanner :char(36)). I want to calculate maximum time as current date then calculate before 30 days date and then find how many no of click between this date range it will not return any output ...

```
   SELECT count(idCampaignBanner) AS TotalClicks 
   FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick 
   WHERE Time BETWEEN   
   (Select max(`Time`) FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick)
  And
   (select max(`Time`)- INTERVAL 30 DAY FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick);
```

Comment: Just do `select max(time)` in a separate query. Should work fine. Also you have double `FROM` clause

Comment: how to write separate query ??? can you please explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
set @max_time:= (SELECT  max(`Time`) FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick );

SELECT count(idCampaignBanner) AS TotalClicks 
   FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick 
   WHERE Time BETWEEN date_add(@max_time, INTERVAL 30 DAY) and @max_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @max_time:= (SELECT  max(`Time`) FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick );

SELECT count(idCampaignBanner) AS TotalClicks 
   FROM newradium.BannerStatsClick 
   WHERE Time BETWEEN  dateadd(day,-30,@max_time) and @max_time
```